# Query for Retrieving

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to build a query which should give me below mentioned output.

```
My table structure                        Required output 

Depth | Name                          Level A | Level B | Level C
1     |A                                 A    |   B     |   C
2     |B                                 A1   |   B1    |   C1
3     |C                                 A1   |   B1    |   C2
1     |A1                                A1   |   B2    |   C3
2     |B1                                A1   |   B2    |   C4
3     |C1                            
3     |C2
2     |B2
3     |C3
3     |C4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the logic used to produce this result?

Comment: which version of oracle db you using ...

Comment: What have you tried so far and why would you expect/require that output? There seems to be no obvious connection between your input and output other than that it's the same letters...

Comment: actually this is hierarchical data where depth will define the level of hierarchy. 1 is father for 2 and 2 is father for 3. so i need in the format mentioned above.

Comment: i  am using 10g version of oracle

Comment: i tried some self joins on table but its not working

Comment: Could this be an instance of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ? Could you explain using a [simple and reproducible use case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) _what_ you are trying to achieve and _how_ you have approached the problem for now. And please, *edit your question* when you need to provide additional details.

Comment: you tried hierarchical query like using connect by path and connect by prior to find the hierarchy ...

Comment: @Abhishekchoudhary . . . SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no way to identify that `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'C'` go together on the same row, unless you have some other identifier that combines them or orders the rows.

Comment: @gordon i have unique sequence number column also in my source table

Comment: You have not explained the rule that assigns `C2` to `B1` but `C3` to `B2`.  Nor have you provided sufficient data for us to figure out the rows by ourselves with any degree of certainty.  Given that this is clearly a toy set of data any solution which might reproduce the desired output is unlikely to be useful in real life.

Comment: @APC , actually it depends on depth ... in hierarchy we have 3 levels...highest level is 1 and lowest is 2... the same hierarchy will continue until we find another 1 in depth ... like 1 is father of 2 and 2 is father of 3 ...like this

Comment: Not good enough.  "hierarchy will continue until we find another 1 in depth " requires some other ordering mechanism to define the order of `depth 1` records, `depth 2` within `depth 1` etc.  Unless the assignment is entirely arbitrary, in which case what is the point?

Answer (score 1):

Given your particular data, you can come close with:

```
select a.name as levela, b.name as levelb, c.name as levelc
from (select name, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from table where depth = 1
     ) a full outer join
     (select name, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from table where depth = 2
     ) b full outer join
     on b.seqnum = a.seqnum
     (select name, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from table where depth = 3
     ) c
     on c.seqnum = coalesce(a.seqnum, b.seqnum);
```

This inserts `NULL`s instead of repeating the final values for the three columns.  If you want the final values, this should work:

```
select coalesce(a.name, maxes.a) as levela,
       coalesce(b.name, maxes.b) as levelb,
       coalesce(c.name, maxes.c) as levelc
from (select name, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from table where depth = 1
     ) a full outer join
     (select name, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from table where depth = 2
     ) b full outer join
     on b.seqnum = a.seqnum
     (select name, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from table where depth = 3
     ) c
     on c.seqnum = coalesce(a.seqnum, b.seqnum) cross join
     (select max(case when depth = 1 and id = maxid then name end) as max_a,
             max(case when depth = 2 and id = maxid then name end) as max_b,
             max(case when depth = 3 and id = maxid then name end) as max_c
      from (select t.*,
                   max(id) over (partition by depth) as maxid
            from t
           ) t
     ) maxes
```

Comment: @Abhishekchoudhary . . . "i have unique sequence number column also in my source table ".  I called that column `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the relationship between levelA,levelB,levelC is not clear.I have assumed you want to return the max(name) in case the corresponding value is not available.The [Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7aa50/6).You can replace 
    `order by my_table.name` into `order by unique_seq_column` and also `max(name) name` by the `name value in max(unique_seq_column)` if it suits your requirement

```
 --Get the max count and max name for each level
 with  cnt_max1 as (select max(name) name ,count(1) cnt from my_table where depth=1)
      ,cnt_max2 as (select max(name) name ,count(1) cnt from my_table where depth=2)
     ,cnt_max3 as (select max(name) name ,count(1) cnt from my_table where depth=3)

--find out the total rows required

,greatest_cnt as (select greatest(cnt_max1.cnt,cnt_max2.cnt,cnt_max3.cnt) cnt from cnt_max1,cnt_max2,cnt_max3)

--Establish relationship between levelA,levelB,levelC using sublevel column

,level_A as (select * from (select rownum sublevel, my_table.name as levela from my_table where depth=1 order by my_table.name)
             union 
             select level+cnt_max1.cnt sublevel,cnt_max1.name levela 
                     from cnt_max1,greatest_cnt connect by level <=(greatest_cnt.cnt - cnt_max1.cnt))

,level_B as (select * from (select rownum sublevel, my_table.name as levelb from my_table where depth=2  order by my_table.name)
             union 
             select level+cnt_max2.cnt sublevel,cnt_max2.name levelb 
             from cnt_max2,greatest_cnt connect by level <=(greatest_cnt.cnt - cnt_max2.cnt))

,level_C as (select * from (select rownum sublevel, my_table.name as levelc from my_table where depth=3 order by my_table.name)
             union 
             select level+cnt_max3.cnt sublevel,cnt_max3.name levelc  
             from cnt_max3,greatest_cnt connect by level <=(greatest_cnt.cnt - cnt_max3.cnt))

--Display the data

select levela,levelb,levelc
from level_A join level_b 
on level_A.sublevel=level_B.sublevel
join level_c on level_C.sublevel=level_b.sublevel
```

Comment: it won't work as pivot clause requires aggregate function .... also @abhishek is using oracle 10g

Comment: @DharmeshPorwal provided a custom solution now